# Dynamically change activity theme

Tags: android, coding-style, load, themes

My application has a generic main activity.
Main activity reads its configuration from arrays.xml like follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="home_buttons_text">
    <item>@string/Title_1</item>
  </string-array>
  <array name="home_buttons_icon">
    <item>@drawable/google</item>
  </array>
  <string-array name="home_buttons_url">
    <item>http://www.google.com</item>
  </string-array>
  <array name="themes">
    <item>@style/my_theme</item>
  </array>
</resources>
```

In this way to add a new icon, i just put new lines here.

So in "themes" I've theme's name. How i can load and apply theme referred by name?

For icons I've used

```
TypedArray mItemsIcons = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.home_buttons_icon);
TypedArray mThemes = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.themes);
.
.
.
mItemsIcons.getDrawable(position);
.
.
.
```

But I've no idea on how to get theme.
I've tested

```
int theme = mThemes.getResourceId(position);
setTheme(theme);
```

but it doesn't work.

Check here for details: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray

Answer (score 4):

you can use `setTheme(..)` before calling `setContentView(...)`and `super.oncreate()`  and it should work fine

Comment: That really helped me: http://javarticles.com/2015/04/android-set-theme-dynamically.html